# Android studio suddenly freezes

Tags: android, android-studio

Have submitted the following bug report for Google. May be somebody faced similar problem?

Android studio 2.1.2 for Windows may suddenly stop responding on keyboard or mouse clicks.
Also, when trying clicking windows close button (cross), nothing happens.

Task manager shows, that AS consumes about 30% of CPU. The only way to stop AS is to kill it via task manager.

Just before freezing the following message occurs in AS status bar:

`null java.nio.BufferOverflowException at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.read(Debugger.java:210) at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processDebuggerData(MonitorThread.java:451) at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processDebuggerActivity(MonitorThread.java:394) at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:259)`

This may occurs in any time, even when just editing text.

Comment: Unfortunately problem is still actual. Watch the issue on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216282